# SQL: Delete Duplicate Records and Update Foreign Key at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Student Table
Id   Name   Age   SectionId
1    Ray    12    1
2    May    11    2
3    Fae    12    3
4    Jay    11    4
5    Zoe    12    5

Section Table
Id   SectionName   Priority
1    A             1
2    B             2
3    A             1
4    B             2
5    A             1
```

I have the two sql tables above. My code failed where duplicate Section records were created for each student with the same Age. The expected result should be:
 1. Only 2 Section records should be created (Section A & B)
 2. The SectionId of Ray, Fae and Zoe should be 1.
 3. The SectionId of May and Jay should be 2.

**I'm having a hard time creating a script to correct the existing records in the database. Can you help me or point me in the right direction to create a script that will:

 1. Delete duplicate Section records (Id 3,4,5)

 2. And update the value of SectionId of Students**

Really appreciate all the help thanks in advance...

Edit:

```
SELECT SectionName, Priority, COUNT(*)
FROM Section
GROUP BY SectionName, Priority
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Currently I can only find records with duplicates

Comment: delete from section where id > 2; update students set sectionid = 1 where id in (1,3,5); update students set sectionid = 2 where id in (2,4);

Comment: @Tomasz it will not work for a scenario where the SectionName of Id=2 is A.

Comment: @Tomasz comments aren't the place for answers. If you're providing an answer, post it as an answer; along with a description of what it does.

Comment: What attempts have you made so far to try to resolve this?

Comment: @Larnu added my current script in my investigation so far. Sorry thats all I have now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to `update` the incorrect section id, followed by a `delete` query to remove the unwanted sections like following.

```
update s
    set s.SectionId =(select min(s1.id) from section s1
    inner join section s2 on s1.sectionname=s2.sectionname
    where s2.id=s.sectionid)
from  student s
```

Followed by delete

```
delete from section where id> 2
```

Note: For delete, you might need to put additional condition like `and SectionName in ('a','b')` if there are other valid records.

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/YNPB83807)